# Div positioning like float left if 2 div and like text-align center if 1 div

Tags: css, html, alignment, css-float

Sorry about that question, but I've tried many things from different answers and nothing works.

This is the HTML :

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="main-col">
    </div>
    <div id="right-col">
    </div>
</div>
```

When there are two divs I want to align them like this :

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4Uj6m)**

But when the `div#right-col` is not there I would like the div#main-col 
to be aligned to center in the div#wrapper like this :

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/at2qX/)**

I tried to replace the float left and right by

```
display: inline-block; left; margin-right: 10px
```

for `main-col` and `right-col` but they stack up in the center.

Do someone have an idea ?

thanks !

Comment: I can't see the difference in the second one. You want #main-col to be in the middle of the screen when #right-col is not there?